# HTTP Request path needs to be parameterized with UUID and a random URL

Tags: performance, jmeter

URL format is

```
www.something.com/something/api/{uuid}?code=gomundw0gjq2kbvc3g63whfr9usap5rurjaq5vui5vm6xbt9hhqa8hbcpto4yatwpn26v42t9
```

I need to make several calls to this GET Url and check performance of the feature.
uuid here is not just the UUID , but is specific to my application

`UUID= accountid+identifierid+uuid`, which will look like `1234+1234+123e4567e89b12d3a456426655440000`

How should I arrange my Jmeter Test Plan.

My Plan would be:

- write UUID generated to a file
- Using any preprocessor call the file from file and write program to append to a different value in the csv which is account/identifierid.

Please help on this, can some one explain how I should logically arrange my test plan and code to get data to parameterize my path in HTTP Request sampler.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to get `accountid+identifierid` information stored into CSV file. This is something you need to do on your own.
2. You can use [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) in order to get the information from that file while your test is running, example configuration would be:

   [image: CSV Data Set Config]
3. UUID can be generated using [__UUID() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID)
4. So your HTTP Request sampler configuration would be something like:

   [image: variable from csv plus function in Http request]